# ExceptionInInitializerError in jdk1.8 not in jdk1.6

Tags: java, opentaps

5 with jdk1.8 when I run the project. I got an Exception `ExceptionInInitializerError`. But when I run the same project in jdk1.6. It is running successfully. That error message as

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>       at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>       at org.ofbiz.entity.GenericDelegator.initEntityEcaHandler(GenericDelegator.java:339)
>       at org.ofbiz.entity.DelegatorFactory.getDelegator(DelegatorFactory.java:42)
>       at org.ofbiz.catalina.container.CatalinaContainer.init(CatalinaContainer.java:175)
>       at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.loadContainer(ContainerLoader.java:189)
>       at org.ofbiz.base.container.ContainerLoader.load(ContainerLoader.java:66)
>       at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.initStartLoaders(Start.java:260)
>       at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.init(Start.java:97)
>       at org.ofbiz.base.start.Start.main(Start.java:411)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Unknown Source)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(AsmClassInfo.java:308)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(AsmClassInfo.java:331)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.createClassInfoFromStream(AsmClassInfo.java:790)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getClassInfo(AsmClassInfo.java:273)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.impl.asm.AsmClassInfo.getInterfaces(AsmClassInfo.java:619)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.reflect.ClassInfoHelper.implementsInterface(ClassInfoHelper.java:56)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPointCompiler.collectCustomProceedMethods(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:237)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPointCompiler.collectCustomProceedMethods(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:208)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPointCompiler.initialize(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:149)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.AbstractJoinPointCompiler.(AbstractJoinPointCompiler.java:133)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.MethodExecutionJoinPointCompiler.(MethodExecutionJoinPointCompiler.java:33)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.transform.inlining.compiler.JoinPointFactory.compileJoinPoint(JoinPointFactory.java:86)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.joinpoint.management.JoinPointManager$CompiledJoinPoint.(JoinPointManager.java:262)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.joinpoint.management.JoinPointManager.compileJoinPoint(JoinPointManager.java:251)
>       at org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.joinpoint.management.JoinPointManager.loadJoinPoint(JoinPointManager.java:118)
>       at org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.aw$initJoinPoints(DelegatorEcaHandler.java)
>       at org.ofbiz.entityext.eca.DelegatorEcaHandler.(DelegatorEcaHandler.java)
>       ... 13 more"

I found two files are problem when I run the project in jdk1.8 that coding files are:
CatalinaContainer.java

```
/**
 * CatalinaContainer -  Tomcat 5
 *
 */
public class CatalinaContainer implements Container {

    public static final String CATALINA_HOSTS_HOME = System.getProperty("ofbiz.home") + "/framework/catalina/hosts";
    public static final String J2EE_SERVER = "OFBiz Container 3.1";
    public static final String J2EE_APP = "OFBiz";
    public static final String module = CatalinaContainer.class.getName();
    protected static Map<String, String> mimeTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // load the JSSE propertes (set the trust store)


 static {
         SSLUtil.loadJsseProperties();
     }
protected Delegator delegator = null;
protected Embedded embedded = null;
protected Map<String, ContainerConfig.Container.Property> clusterConfig = new HashMap<String, ContainerConfig.Container.Property>();
protected Map<String, Engine> engines = new HashMap<String, Engine>();
protected Map<String, Host> hosts = new HashMap<String, Host>();

protected boolean contextReloadable = false;
protected boolean crossContext = false;
protected boolean distribute = false;

protected boolean enableDefaultMimeTypes = true;

protected String catalinaRuntimeHome;

/**
 * @see org.ofbiz.base.container.Container#init(java.lang.String[], java.lang.String)
 */
public void init(String[] args, String configFile) throws ContainerException {
    // get the container config
    ContainerConfig.Container cc = ContainerConfig.getContainer("catalina-container", configFile);
    if (cc == null) {
        throw new ContainerException("No catalina-container configuration found in container config!");
    }

    // embedded properties
    boolean useNaming = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "use-naming", false);
    //int debug = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "debug", 0);

    // grab some global context settings
    this.delegator = DelegatorFactory.getDelegator(ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "delegator-name", "default"));
    this.contextReloadable = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "apps-context-reloadable", false);
    this.crossContext = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "apps-cross-context", true);
    this.distribute = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "apps-distributable", true);

    this.catalinaRuntimeHome = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(cc, "catalina-runtime-home", "runtime/catalina");

    // set catalina_home
    System.setProperty("catalina.home", System.getProperty("ofbiz.home") + "/" + this.catalinaRuntimeHome);

    // configure JNDI in the StandardServer
    StandardServer server = (StandardServer) ServerFactory.getServer();
    try {
        server.setGlobalNamingContext(new InitialContext());
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        throw new ContainerException(e);
    }

    // create the instance of Embedded
    embedded = new Embedded();
    embedded.setUseNaming(useNaming);

    // create the engines
    List<ContainerConfig.Container.Property> engineProps = cc.getPropertiesWithValue("engine");
    if (UtilValidate.isEmpty(engineProps)) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cannot load CatalinaContainer; no engines defined!");
    }
    for (ContainerConfig.Container.Property engineProp: engineProps) {
        createEngine(engineProp);
    }

    // load the web applications
    loadComponents();

    // create the connectors
    List<ContainerConfig.Container.Property> connectorProps = cc.getPropertiesWithValue("connector");
    if (UtilValidate.isEmpty(connectorProps)) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cannot load CatalinaContainer; no connectors defined!");
    }
    for (ContainerConfig.Container.Property connectorProp: connectorProps) {
        createConnector(connectorProp);
    }

    try {
        embedded.initialize();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
        throw new ContainerException(e);
    }
}

public boolean start() throws ContainerException {
    // Start the embedded server
    try {
        embedded.start();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
        throw new ContainerException(e);
    }

    for (Connector con: embedded.findConnectors()) {
        ProtocolHandler ph = con.getProtocolHandler();
        if (ph instanceof Http11Protocol) {
            Http11Protocol hph = (Http11Protocol) ph;
            Debug.logInfo("Connector " + hph.getProtocols() + " @ " + hph.getPort() + " - " +
                (hph.getSecure() ? "secure" : "not-secure") + " [" + con.getProtocolHandlerClassName() + "] started.", module);
        } else {
            Debug.logInfo("Connector " + con.getProtocol() + " @ " + con.getPort() + " - " +
                (con.getSecure() ? "secure" : "not-secure") + " [" + con.getProtocolHandlerClassName() + "] started.", module);
        }
    }
    Debug.logInfo("Started " + ServerInfo.getServerInfo(), module);
    return true;
}

protected Engine createEngine(ContainerConfig.Container.Property engineConfig) throws ContainerException {
    if (embedded == null) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cannot create Engine without Embedded instance!");
    }

    ContainerConfig.Container.Property defaultHostProp = engineConfig.getProperty("default-host");
    if (defaultHostProp == null) {
        throw new ContainerException("default-host element of server property is required for catalina!");
    }

    String engineName = engineConfig.name;
    String hostName = defaultHostProp.value;

    StandardEngine engine = (StandardEngine) embedded.createEngine();
    engine.setName(engineName);
    engine.setDefaultHost(hostName);

    // set the JVM Route property (JK/JK2)
    String jvmRoute = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "jvm-route", null);
    if (jvmRoute != null) {
        engine.setJvmRoute(jvmRoute);
    }

    // create the default realm -- TODO: make this configurable
    String dbConfigPath = "catalina-users.xml";
    MemoryRealm realm = new MemoryRealm();
    realm.setPathname(dbConfigPath);
    engine.setRealm(realm);

    // cache the engine
    engines.put(engine.getName(), engine);

    // create a default virtual host; others will be created as needed
    Host host = createHost(engine, hostName);
    hosts.put(engineName + "._DEFAULT", host);

    // configure clustering
    List<ContainerConfig.Container.Property> clusterProps = engineConfig.getPropertiesWithValue("cluster");
    if (clusterProps != null && clusterProps.size() > 1) {
        throw new ContainerException("Only one cluster configuration allowed per engine");
    }

    if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(clusterProps)) {
        ContainerConfig.Container.Property clusterProp = clusterProps.get(0);
        createCluster(clusterProp, host);
        clusterConfig.put(engineName, clusterProp);
    }

    // request dumper valve
    boolean enableRequestDump = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "enable-request-dump", false);
    if (enableRequestDump) {
        RequestDumperValve rdv = new RequestDumperValve();
        engine.addValve(rdv);
    }

    // configure the CrossSubdomainSessionValve
    boolean enableSessionValve = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "enable-cross-subdomain-sessions", false);
    if (enableSessionValve) {
        CrossSubdomainSessionValve sessionValve = new CrossSubdomainSessionValve();
        engine.addValve(sessionValve);
    }

    // configure the access log valve
    String logDir = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "access-log-dir", null);
    AccessLogValve al = null;
    if (logDir != null) {
        al = new AccessLogValve();
        if (!logDir.startsWith("/")) {
            logDir = System.getProperty("ofbiz.home") + "/" + logDir;
        }
        File logFile = new File(logDir);
        if (!logFile.isDirectory()) {
            throw new ContainerException("Log directory [" + logDir + "] is not available; make sure the directory is created");
        }
        al.setDirectory(logFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    // configure the SslAcceleratorValve
    String sslAcceleratorPortStr = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "ssl-accelerator-port", null);
    if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(sslAcceleratorPortStr)) {
        Integer sslAcceleratorPort = Integer.valueOf(sslAcceleratorPortStr);
        SslAcceleratorValve sslAcceleratorValve = new SslAcceleratorValve();
        sslAcceleratorValve.setSslAcceleratorPort(sslAcceleratorPort);
        engine.addValve(sslAcceleratorValve);
    }


    String alp2 = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "access-log-pattern", null);
    if (al != null && !UtilValidate.isEmpty(alp2)) {
        al.setPattern(alp2);
    }

    String alp3 = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "access-log-prefix", null);
    if (al != null && !UtilValidate.isEmpty(alp3)) {
        al.setPrefix(alp3);
    }


    boolean alp4 = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "access-log-resolve", true);
    if (al != null) {
        al.setResolveHosts(alp4);
    }

    boolean alp5 = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(engineConfig, "access-log-rotate", false);
    if (al != null) {
        al.setRotatable(alp5);
    }

    if (al != null) {
        engine.addValve(al);
    }

    embedded.addEngine(engine);
    return engine;
}

protected Host createHost(Engine engine, String hostName) throws ContainerException {
    if (embedded == null) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cannot create Host without Embedded instance!");
    }

    Host host = embedded.createHost(hostName, CATALINA_HOSTS_HOME);
    host.setDeployOnStartup(true);
    host.setAutoDeploy(true);
    host.setRealm(engine.getRealm());
    engine.addChild(host);
    hosts.put(engine.getName() + hostName, host);

    return host;
}

protected Cluster createCluster(ContainerConfig.Container.Property clusterProps, Host host) throws ContainerException {
    String defaultValveFilter = ".*.gif;.*.js;.*.jpg;.*.htm;.*.html;.*.txt;";

    ReplicationValve clusterValve = new ReplicationValve();
    clusterValve.setFilter(ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "rep-valve-filter", defaultValveFilter));

    String mcb = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "mcast-bind-addr", null);
    String mca = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "mcast-addr", null);
    int mcp = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "mcast-port", -1);
    int mcf = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "mcast-freq", 500);
    int mcd = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "mcast-drop-time", 3000);

    if (mca == null || mcp == -1) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cluster configuration requires mcast-addr and mcast-port properties");
    }

    McastService mcast = new McastService();
    if (mcb != null) {
        mcast.setMcastBindAddress(mcb);
    }

    mcast.setAddress(mca);
    mcast.setPort(mcp);
    mcast.setMcastDropTime(mcd);
    mcast.setFrequency(mcf);

    String tla = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "tcp-listen-host", "auto");
    int tlp = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "tcp-listen-port", 4001);
    int tlt = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "tcp-sector-timeout", 100);
    int tlc = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "tcp-thread-count", 6);
    //String tls = getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "", "");

    if (tlp == -1) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cluster configuration requires tcp-listen-port property");
    }

    NioReceiver listener = new NioReceiver();
    listener.setAddress(tla);
    listener.setPort(tlp);
    listener.setSelectorTimeout(tlt);
    listener.setMaxThreads(tlc);
    listener.setMinThreads(tlc);
    //listener.setIsSenderSynchronized(false);

    ReplicationTransmitter trans = new ReplicationTransmitter();
    try {
        MultiPointSender mps = (MultiPointSender)Class.forName(ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "replication-mode", "org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.bio.PooledMultiSender")).newInstance();
        trans.setTransport(mps);
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cluster configuration requires a valid replication-mode property: " + exc.getMessage());
    }
    String mgrClassName = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "manager-class", "org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager");
    //int debug = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "debug", 0);
    // removed since 5.5.9? boolean expireSession = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "expire-session", false);
    // removed since 5.5.9? boolean useDirty = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProps, "use-dirty", true);

    SimpleTcpCluster cluster = new SimpleTcpCluster();
    cluster.setClusterName(clusterProps.name);
    Manager manager = null;
    try {
        manager = (Manager)Class.forName(mgrClassName).newInstance();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cluster configuration requires a valid manager-class property: " + exc.getMessage());
    }
    //cluster.setManagerClassName(mgrClassName);
    //host.setManager(manager);
    //cluster.registerManager(manager);
    cluster.setManagerTemplate((org.apache.catalina.ha.ClusterManager)manager);
    //cluster.setDebug(debug);
    // removed since 5.5.9? cluster.setExpireSessionsOnShutdown(expireSession);
    // removed since 5.5.9? cluster.setUseDirtyFlag(useDirty);

    GroupChannel channel = new GroupChannel();
    channel.setChannelReceiver(listener);
    channel.setChannelSender(trans);
    channel.setMembershipService(mcast);

    cluster.setChannel(channel);
    cluster.addValve(clusterValve);
    // removed since 5.5.9? cluster.setPrintToScreen(true);

    // set the cluster to the host
    host.setCluster(cluster);
    Debug.logInfo("Catalina Cluster [" + cluster.getClusterName() + "] configured for host - " + host.getName(), module);

    return cluster;
}

protected Connector createConnector(ContainerConfig.Container.Property connectorProp) throws ContainerException {
    if (embedded == null) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cannot create Connector without Embedded instance!");
    }

    // need some standard properties
    String protocol = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(connectorProp, "protocol", "HTTP/1.1");
    String address = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(connectorProp, "address", "0.0.0.0");
    int port = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(connectorProp, "port", 0);
    boolean secure = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(connectorProp, "secure", false);
    if (protocol.toLowerCase().startsWith("ajp")) {
        protocol = "ajp";
    } else if ("memory".equals(protocol.toLowerCase())) {
        protocol = "memory";
    } else if (secure) {
        protocol = "https";
    } else {
        protocol = "http";
    }

    Connector connector = null;
    if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(connectorProp.properties)) {
        connector = embedded.createConnector(address, port, protocol);
        try {
            for (ContainerConfig.Container.Property prop: connectorProp.properties.values()) {
                connector.setProperty(prop.name, prop.value);
                //connector.setAttribute(prop.name, prop.value);
            }
            embedded.addConnector(connector);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new ContainerException(e);
        }
    }
    return connector;
}

protected Context createContext(ComponentConfig.WebappInfo appInfo) throws ContainerException {
    // webapp settings
    Map<String, String> initParameters = appInfo.getInitParameters();
    List<String> virtualHosts = appInfo.getVirtualHosts();
    Engine engine = engines.get(appInfo.server);
    if (engine == null) {
        Debug.logWarning("Server with name [" + appInfo.server + "] not found; not mounting [" + appInfo.name + "]", module);
        return null;
    }

    // set the root location (make sure we set the paths correctly)
    String location = appInfo.componentConfig.getRootLocation() + appInfo.location;
    location = location.replace('\\', '/');
    if (location.endsWith("/")) {
        location = location.substring(0, location.length() - 1);
    }

    // get the mount point
    String mount = appInfo.mountPoint;
    if (mount.endsWith("/*")) {
        mount = mount.substring(0, mount.length() - 2);
    }

    // configure persistent sessions
    Property clusterProp = clusterConfig.get(engine.getName());

    Manager sessionMgr = null;
    if (clusterProp != null) {
        String mgrClassName = ContainerConfig.getPropertyValue(clusterProp, "manager-class", "org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager");
        try {
            sessionMgr = (Manager)Class.forName(mgrClassName).newInstance();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            throw new ContainerException("Cluster configuration requires a valid manager-class property: " + exc.getMessage());
        }
    } else {
        sessionMgr = new StandardManager();
    }

    // create the web application context
    StandardContext context = (StandardContext) embedded.createContext(mount, location);
    context.setJ2EEApplication(J2EE_APP);
    context.setJ2EEServer(J2EE_SERVER);
    context.setLoader(embedded.createLoader(ClassLoaderContainer.getClassLoader()));

    context.setCookies(appInfo.isSessionCookieAccepted());
    context.addParameter("cookies", appInfo.isSessionCookieAccepted() ? "true" : "false");

    context.setDisplayName(appInfo.name);
    context.setDocBase(location);
    context.setAllowLinking(true);

    context.setReloadable(contextReloadable);
    context.setDistributable(distribute);
    context.setCrossContext(crossContext);
    context.setPrivileged(appInfo.privileged);
    context.setManager(sessionMgr);
    context.getServletContext().setAttribute("_serverId", appInfo.server);
    context.getServletContext().setAttribute("componentName", appInfo.componentConfig.getComponentName());

    // create the Default Servlet instance to mount
    StandardWrapper defaultServlet = new StandardWrapper();
    defaultServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet");
    defaultServlet.setServletName("default");
    defaultServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    defaultServlet.addInitParameter("debug", "0");
    defaultServlet.addInitParameter("listing", "true");
    defaultServlet.addMapping("/");
    context.addChild(defaultServlet);
    context.addServletMapping("/", "default");

    // create the Jasper Servlet instance to mount
    StandardWrapper jspServlet = new StandardWrapper();
    jspServlet.setServletClass("org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet");
    jspServlet.setServletName("jsp");
    jspServlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    jspServlet.addInitParameter("fork", "false");
    jspServlet.addInitParameter("xpoweredBy", "true");
    jspServlet.addMapping("*.jsp");
    jspServlet.addMapping("*.jspx");
    context.addChild(jspServlet);
    context.addServletMapping("*.jsp", "jsp");

    // default mime-type mappings
    configureMimeTypes(context);

    // set the init parameters
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: initParameters.entrySet()) {
        context.addParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    if (UtilValidate.isEmpty(virtualHosts)) {
        Host host = hosts.get(engine.getName() + "._DEFAULT");
        context.setRealm(host.getRealm());
        host.addChild(context);
        context.getMapper().setDefaultHostName(host.getName());
    } else {
        // assume that the first virtual-host will be the default; additional virtual-hosts will be aliases
        Iterator<String> vhi = virtualHosts.iterator();
        String hostName = vhi.next();

        boolean newHost = false;
        Host host = hosts.get(engine.getName() + "." + hostName);
        if (host == null) {
            host = createHost(engine, hostName);
            newHost = true;
        }
        while (vhi.hasNext()) {
            host.addAlias(vhi.next());
        }
        context.setRealm(host.getRealm());
        host.addChild(context);
        context.getMapper().setDefaultHostName(host.getName());

        if (newHost) {
            hosts.put(engine.getName() + "." + hostName, host);
        }
    }

    return context;
}

protected void loadComponents() throws ContainerException {
    if (embedded == null) {
        throw new ContainerException("Cannot load web applications without Embedded instance!");
    }

    // load the applications
    List<ComponentConfig.WebappInfo> webResourceInfos = ComponentConfig.getAllWebappResourceInfos();
    List<String> loadedMounts = FastList.newInstance();
    if (webResourceInfos != null) {
        for (int i = webResourceInfos.size(); i > 0; i--) {
            ComponentConfig.WebappInfo appInfo = webResourceInfos.get(i - 1);
            String mount = appInfo.getContextRoot();
            if (!loadedMounts.contains(mount)) {
                createContext(appInfo);
                loadedMounts.add(mount);
            } else {
                appInfo.appBarDisplay = false; // disable app bar display on overrided apps
                Debug.logInfo("Duplicate webapp mount; not loading : " + appInfo.getName() + " / " + appInfo.getLocation(), module);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void stop() throws ContainerException {
    try {
        embedded.stop();
    } catch (LifecycleException e) {
        // don't throw this; or it will kill the rest of the shutdown process
        Debug.logVerbose(e, module); // happens usually when running tests, disabled unless in verbose
    }
}

protected void configureMimeTypes(Context context) throws ContainerException {
    Map<String, String> mimeTypes = CatalinaContainer.getMimeTypes();
    if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(mimeTypes)) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry: mimeTypes.entrySet()) {
            context.addMimeMapping(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }
}

protected static synchronized Map<String, String> getMimeTypes() throws ContainerException {
    if (UtilValidate.isNotEmpty(mimeTypes)) {
        return mimeTypes;
    }

    if (mimeTypes == null) mimeTypes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    URL xmlUrl = UtilURL.fromResource("mime-type.xml");

    // read the document
    Document mimeTypeDoc;
    try {
        mimeTypeDoc = UtilXml.readXmlDocument(xmlUrl, true);
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        throw new ContainerException("Error reading the mime-type.xml config file: " + xmlUrl, e);
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        throw new ContainerException("Error reading the mime-type.xml config file: " + xmlUrl, e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ContainerException("Error reading the mime-type.xml config file: " + xmlUrl, e);
    }

    if (mimeTypeDoc == null) {
        Debug.logError("Null document returned for mime-type.xml", module);
        return null;
    }

    // root element
    Element root = mimeTypeDoc.getDocumentElement();

    // mapppings
    for (Element curElement: UtilXml.childElementList(root, "mime-mapping")) {
        String extension = UtilXml.childElementValue(curElement, "extension");
        String type = UtilXml.childElementValue(curElement, "mime-type");
        mimeTypes.put(extension, type);
    }

    return mimeTypes;
}
```

}

Class.class file

```
try {
            return tmpConstructor.newInstance((Object[])null);
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            Unsafe.getUnsafe().throwException(e.getTargetException());
            // Not reached
            return null;
        }
```

I'm confused state. Please help me to recover this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the stacktrace there is a

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5747 at
org.codehaus.aspectwerkz.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readClass(Unknown Source)
```

[ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) is a tool to read and manipulate Java class files.

There have been changes to the class file format between JDK 6 and 8 and you (most probably) have an outdated version of ASM which runs into problems when reading Java 8 class files.

To solve the issue try to upgrade to the latest version of ASM (or Ofbiz).

**EDIT:** As commented by integratingweb Opentaps only supports JDK 6.

Comment: Hi @wero, Thank you for your response. I'm new to opentaps. When I upgrade my ofbiz version 10 to 13(latest version) I have compiler issue like javac17. Please let me how to upgrade ASM or Ofbiz. NOTE: Now My system configuration as opentaps1.5, ofbiz 10 and apache 6.0.26 and jdk1.8

Comment: @VignesvarAsokkumar unfortunately I am not an expert in opentaps or ofbiz and their versioning. But you could ask another question on stackoverflow or on an opentaps/ofbiz mailinglist what version would suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response @wero. I was installed ASM latest plugin into eclipse but still I got same exception. Anyway Thanks again for your valuable suggestion. Have a nice day.

Comment: Please note that Opentaps does not support java 8.  You must use java 6